# Область видимости файла и прототипы функций

Tags: c++, компилятор, компоновщик

У нас есть 2 файла `main.cpp` и `lib.cpp`. В первом у нас лежит, какой нибудь код, а во втором определение некоторой функции. Так вот, насколько я понимаю у каждого из этих файлов своя область видимости, тоесть если мы определим переменную в `lib.cpp`, то работать с ней в `main.cpp` не получится. Аналогично и с функцией которая лежит в `lib.cpp`, без объявления прототипа ее вызвать не получится. Так вот, как работает прототип? Получается он даёт команду компилятору о том, что бы искать данное имя где-то в коде (например в другом файле) и таким образом он грубо говоря "ломает" (разрешает) эти области видимости? И имеет ли файл свою область видимости?

Comment: Примерно так: весь код скидывается в одну помойку, но чтобы вызвать функцию, ее прототип должен быть выше вызова, а тело уже найдется по прототипу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте все же разделять чисто компиляцию и компоновку.

*Примерно* так. Прототип говорит компилятору - где-то - не твое дело, где - будет функция `void f(int)` (ну, или какой там у вас прототип). Все. Действуй так, как будто она есть.

OK, говорит компилятор, и в нужном месте вставляет команду типа

```
CALL f@int  ; ну, или как он ее там обзовет
```

В машинном коде, грубо говоря, остается место для адреса, а в какой-то таблице записывается - в таком-то месте надо подставить правильный адрес.

В библиотечном файле компиляция выполняется полностью, и есть где-то что-то вроде

```
PROC f@int
```

Когда компоновщик берется за дело, он, грубо говоря, сводит воедино таблицы мест, куда надо подставить верный адрес, и таблицы имен с адресами, и заполняет нужные места адресами (на самом деле, не совсем адресами, сами адреса будут подставляться уже во время загрузки для выполнения, но это уже детали. Важно, что больше не останется никаких записей "вот тут не знаю, откуда брать эту функцию/переменную, разберитесь потом".)

Упрощенно - примерно так. Многие конкретные детали зависят от операционки, компилятора, режима работы процессора и прочего, но смысл примерно такой.

Область видимости - это понятие времени компиляции, а разрешение связей происходит при компоновке. Так что прототип как раз скорее дает команду компилятору **НЕ** искать данное имя где-то в коде ("байт даю, потом это имя будет!")...

Comment: То есть область видимости это просто "побочный эффект" при компиляции или так и задумывалось?

Comment: Простите, не понял ваш вопрос... :(

Comment: Вы сказали, то что "Область видимости - это понятие времени компиляции". И я не совсем понимаю в каком смысле, можете пожалуйста объяснить для чайника(

Comment: В том плане, что когда программа уже линкуется - никакой области видимости уже нет. Какая область видимости в машинном коде?...

Comment: То есть предположим у нас есть две переменные с одинаковым именем, но в двух разных файлах. И в машинном коде они просто будут иметь разные адреса и так-же с функциями?

Comment: Это уже не совсем область видимости. Впрочем, мы вступаем на скользкую тропу трактования стандарта и терминов, это не моя сильная сторона. Поскольку я обычно могу писать нужные мне программы, то не стараюсь учить других, как это делать :) Словом, с терминологическими проблемами и философской трактовкой того, как именно трактуется буква "а" в 15-м слове на 842-й странице - с этим не ко мне  :( Так сказать, когда я хожу - меня обычно не волнует, как называются мышцы ног и в какой последовательности их надо напрягать...

Comment: Что-то я совсем запутался:( У нас есть 2 файла с одинаковыми переменными int a(у них одинаковые названия). Что с ними происходит при переводе в машинный код? Идентификаторы же одинаковые.

Comment: Если это два одинаковых `a` - т.е. не объявленные `static` или `inline` - то получим сообщение от линкера о дублировании имен. Если `static` - то это будут две разные переменные с разными адресами.. Если `inline` - то единственная переменная с одним адресом.